# Why are 3 moderator positions available in the December 2014 election?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

Recently Willie Wong [announced](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17372/announcement-im-retiring) that he is retiring as moderator.  A [moderator election](https://math.stackexchange.com/election) just started, in which there are 3 available positions.  This makes me wonder:

Are other moderator retirements expected soon?  Will we have an increase in the number of moderators?  How was the number 3 determined?

Comment: I suspect that a die was cast.

Comment: If you have been following the moderators user profiles, you might notice that one of them has been mostly inactive for quite some time now. It might be reasonable to speculate this moderator will be replaced as well.

Comment: We consulted [The Book of Armaments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOrgLj9lOwk).

Comment: Thank god! robjohn is not leaving!

Comment: @robjohn: That might be one of the best comments on meta. I demand that a special badge in the shape, color and consistency of Eric Idle will be awarded to you.

Comment: *How was the number $3$ determined ?* $-~3=\lfloor\pi\rfloor=\lceil e\rceil$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: no, we flipped a coin. And both sides were heads. [There's some truth to that: the mods had a long discussion about the number and of those who voted (I didn't, since I don't think it was my place to in this instance) chose 3 as the number.]

Comment: @Willie: Is this because 3 is between 4 and 2, also known as 42, also known as The Answer?

Comment: If I recall correctly, there was an instance where a moderator retired but no new election was held. Perhaps this is why there are 3 positions available.

Comment: @user157227: See the quote of Arthur Fischer in the second comment.

Comment: I guessed correctly about Alex.

Comment: 3 new mods?  Half-Life 3 confirmed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The official moderator response:

> We consulted [The Book of Armaments.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOrgLj9lOwk) –  robjohn♦ Dec 9 at 0:59

---

As indicated in the comments, one other moderator retired, and the number of moderators increased by $1$.

Comment: [Click here for results.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18879/2014-election-results-congratulations-to-the-new-moderators)